# Whats my default git repo for commiting?

Tags: git, commit

If I type git remote -v I get a number of git repos:

```
origin  git@github.com:me/MyProject.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:me/MyProject.git (push)
testheroku  git@heroku.com:test.git (fetch)
testheroku  git@heroku.com:test.git (push)
upstream    git://github.com:me/MyProject.git (fetch)
upstream    git://github.com:me/MyProject.git (push)
```

I've just done ran "git commit" on the README file and would have expected this to update the file on MyProject.git - this does not appear to be the case. Am I wrong?

Also, can somebody clarify what upstream is? Does it mean I'm ahead of a branch or what exactly?

Thanks,
  Gearoid.

Answer (score 4):

Commits are local. You need to push them.

```
git push origin mybranch # this is probably master in your case
```

If you do this all the time, you can set up defaults as to which remotes the changes will be pushed. Then you can just

```
git push
```

and your changes from any branches will go up to any remotes depending on your configuration. The first time you push, you can

```
git push -u origin mybranch
```

and this will set up that branch to automatically be included for pushing to that repository. A subsequent

```
git push
```

will be equivelant to

```
git push origin mybranch
```

To get more familiar, take a look at

```
git remote show
git remote show origin
git config -l
```

Also, you probably don't need the last remote. You can get rid of it with

```
git remote rm upstream
```

Hope this helps

Comment: any time! Hope it all goes well!

Answer (score 1):

When you commit, you're committing to your local repository.  Every git working directory has an associated repo.

origin, testheroku, and upstream are all remotes you can easily push and pull from (you can also explicitly use a repo not listed).

If you do:

```
git push
```

it will probably (depending on configuration) push to `origin`'s `master` branch automatically.

Also, the first and third appear to to be the same repos, just with different URLs.

You can also create branches as needed locally, but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote -v show
git branch -vv
git config branch.$branch.remote
```

`git remote -v show` shows interesting information about your remotes

The `git branch -vv` command will show you your upstream for a specific branch which is *probably* where you push to by default.

However `git config branch.master.remote` would be the only absolute method to know for sure where you push to when you say `git push`